# Segmentation fault when using dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

The following code-snippet is a MWE of an issue I'm encountering with `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class foo {
private:
    int x;
public:
    foo() : x(0) {}
    foo(int xx) : x(xx) {}
    virtual ~foo() = default;
    int get_x() const { return x; }
};

class bar : public foo {
private:
    double y;
public:
    bar(double yy) : foo(), y(yy) {}
    double get_y() const { return y; }
};

int main(void) {
    bar b(0.5);
    std::shared_ptr<foo> fptr = std::make_shared<foo>(b);
    std::cout << (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<bar>(fptr))->get_x();
    return 0;
}
```

This program segfaults at the output stream line (`std::cout << ...`) presumably because the `dynamic_pointer_cast` is resulting in a `nullptr`, but I'm not sure why this is the case?

Any assistance is appreciated, plus here is a [Coliru link to the snippet too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0de06cae4b74677).

Comment: Did you expect `dynamic_pointer_cast<>` to actually **convert** its parameter? That's not what it does, it only **verifies** that the object is of the right type.

Comment: @Frank well, forgive me, it's been a while since I've done any c++ programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `fptr` manages a pointer which pointing to a `foo` in fact. When you down-cast it to pointer to `bar` via dynamic_cast the cast would fail and you'll get a null pointer.

If `fptr` points to a `bar` then it'll work. e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> fptr = std::make_shared<bar>(b);
```

Comment: I see, well that was easy enough to explain then, thanks.